# Unit testing with Mock when viewmodel contains an ICommand

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, viewmodel, icommand

I have a class (for simplicity I'll call it MyCustomCommand) which basically accepts two Delegates for Execute and CanExecute.  This class implements ICommand.  This then allows me to declare a property in my view model which I bind to from XAML.

The problem is I've run into a scenario where I need to Mock the view model due to a dependency in one of my commands called ApplyChangesCommand.  I'm not convinced the dependency is a bad thing yet.  It's relatively necessary at this point.

Because of this dependency, I'm using Mock Setups to create a Callback which basically "does nothing" to circumvent the dependency.

Now that I've Mock'd the view model, any instance properties are of course now null.  This includes my commands.

Simple example would be:

```
private void _somethingToExecute;
public ICommand ApplyChangesCommand { get { return MyCustomCommand(_somethingToExecute, e=>true); }
```

Is there any way with Mock that I can actually invoke ApplyChangesCommand's _somethingToExecute?  Callbase doesn't cut it and I can't think of any other way to do it.

One workaround is to make "_somethingToExecute" public and create the ApplyChangesCommand in my test, but I'm not a fan.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I had to read it a couple of times to try to get at what you're asking, so I may be off here.  Are you having issues unit testing the Command or the ViewModel containing the Command?  If the Command (which is what I think you're asking), can't you just mock the incoming delegate to the `MyCustomCommand` constructor, and just verify that the mock delegate is called?  That would be a correct unit test for the command.  Testing the ViewModel would be similar - mock the Command and have its `Execute` call invoke `_somethingToExecute`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.  Let me look into that...sounds like it might be on the right track!

My issue really revolves around unit testing the Command because I'm Mock'ing the View Model.  Since the View Model is mock'ed the command itself is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that I've had more time to look at this not being rushed at work, I see the issue.  What you should do is use an injected factory to create the `ApplyChangesCommand`.  Then for unit testing your VM, you just verify that the command returns the factory created command.  Below is an example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyCustomCommandFactory _commandFactory;
    private void _somethingToExecute;

    public MyViewModel(MyCustomCommandFactory commandFactory)
    {
        _commandFactory = commandFactory;
    }

    public ICommand ApplyChangesCommand  
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _commandFactory.Create(_somethingToExecute, e=>true);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you're wanting to create a new command every time the get is called (which seems to be how you have it set up).  If you want just a single command created for the life of the VM, obviously you can just create the command via the factory in the VM constructor.

To unit test this, you can do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void ApplyChangesCommand_Always_ReturnsFactoryCreatedCommand
{
    Mock<ICommand> mockCreatedCustomCommand = new Mock<ICommand>();
    Mock<MyCustomCommandFactory> mockCommandFactory = new Mock<MyCustomCommandFactory>();
    mockCreatedCustomCommand.Setup(p => p.Create(It.IsAny<Action>(), e => true))
                            .Returns(mockCreatedCustomCommand.Object);
    Assert.That(systemUnderTest.ApplyChangesCommand, Is.SameAs(mockCreatedCustomCommand.Object));
}
```

(Change `Action` out for whatever your delegate actually is).

This is all you should have to unit test for a VM's command.  If you're wanting to test that the behavior is what you expect (meaning, it executes the passed in delegate and returns the expected value using that delegate), then that's the realm of an acceptance tests.

Note: I used the Moq mocking framework syntax in my test example.

Personally, I wouldn't be passing in delegates like that to a `Command`.  I would instead inject whatever the `Command` needs and have all the logic inside the `Command`, where it is more easily unit tested in there, and has a looser dependency on the VM.